# Augment ruby $LOAD_PATH with ENV['PATH'] still fails to find backtick command

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, path, git-bash

I'm trying to run a program called `pdfgrep` from within a ruby script (Ruby 1.9.3), which is run from a Git Bash (MINGW32) shell on Windows 7. The call to `pdfgrep` is within backticks, I would like to get the result and clean it up using ruby methods.

After viewing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1791080/1793716) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1873882/1793716) to [a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789865/why-cant-i-call-javac-using-the-backquotes-backticks-approach-in-ruby), I figured I should convert the `ENV['PATH']` variable to unix paths from the Windows style paths that is the default in my shell.

(Line 3) So I have tested the contents of `$LOAD_PATH` with a simple `puts`, and that seems to be working.

**script.rb**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ENV['PATH'].split('\\').join(File::SEPARATOR).split(';').inject($LOAD_PATH) {|lp,v| lp << v }

# The intention is to replace puts with a variable assignment
puts  `pdfgrep -i "(issued|Total)" *.pdf`
```

The error I get when running this is:

```
./script.rb:6:in ``': No such file or directory - pdfgrep -i "(issued|Total)" *.pdf (Errno::ENOENT)
```

When I supply the full path - `c:/Users/cjross/bin/pdfgrep -i [etc...]` - there is no error message. It still doesn't output what I expect but it doesn't raise an error.

Basically I would love to be able to call any program in my shell's `$PATH` from ruby. Any advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Thank you @konsolebox for correcting my incorrect quoting. Still have the path issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
puts `pdfgrep -i '(issued|Total)' "*.pdf"`
```

I think should work as

```
puts `pdfgrep -i "(issued|Total)" *.pdf`
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still raises the error about `No such file or directory`, however your revision of my quotes has at least allowed me to get the intended output (albeit with the full path to `pdfgrep`). thanks! I will include it in my question.